# Show wc_add_notice only one time

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have the this code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3 );
function custom_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    $_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $quantity_total = (array_sum($_POST['quantity']));
    // echo $quantity_total;

    if ($quantity_total % 2 != 0) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Multiple of 2 required quantity.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        $passed = false;
    }
    else{
        $passed = true;
    }var_dump($quantity_total);

    return $passed;
}
```

I have a grouped product with many items in & for each product if the condition it's true i'm getting this notice..but I want to display it just one time. Now is displayed error message for each input .. from page of each product, what I want is to display just a single time.

Comment: use `wc_clear_notices();` before `wc_add_notice();`.

Comment: @RaunakGupta you are a genius! Put your solution as an answer to give you +1.

Answer (score 4):

> If you want to remove all the previous messages then you have to use
>   [`wc_clear_notices()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_clear_notices.html) before [`wc_add_notice()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_add_notice.html).

So your code should look like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3);

function custom_add_to_cart_validation($passed, $product_id, $quantity)
{
    //...
    //...
    if ($quantity_total % 2 != 0)
    {
        wc_clear_notices(); //<--- check this line.
        wc_add_notice(__('Multiple of 2 required quantity.', 'woocommerce'), 'error');
        $passed = false;
    }
    //...
    //...
}
```

Hope this helps!